# Impossible declare string type in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following error:

[image]

Any clue what do I am missing?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: *"skipped when looking for precompiled header use"* is important here. If you have an `#include "stdafx.h"` in your file, everything before that will just be skipped.

Comment: @NathanOliver I cannot provide the complete project in order exam it and as well as the question is a simple itself for someone WHO KNOWS Visual C++.

Comment: Try removing precompiled header in project settings (unless, of course, you need it), and try again.

Comment: @Dimi but could could post a snippet of the actual code that is causing the error instead working code from one project and errors from another.  Does you second code have `#include "stdafx.h"` in it as the code you have posted doesn't?

Comment: @NathanOliver I just got the correct answer of the user  matz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is in the warnings: the `#include <string>` is ignored because it's apparently after the include of the precompiled header file. Make sure the precompiled header is included first.

Background: If the corresponding project setting is enabled, the Visual C++ Compiler will, in a pre-preprocesser step, replace the line `#include "stdafx.h"` (this is the default name for the file, it can be changed) with some proprietary blob that contains the content of the stdafx.h in a preprocessed form that the compiler can process more quickly than the actual text content. For this to be useful, the context in which the precompiled header file is used has to be identical to the context it was created in. The Visual C++ Compiler enforces this by simply scrapping everything that comes before the include of the precompiled header.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is correct. I just have to know more about precompiled header file. Would you mind to add to your answer about precompiled headers and why we have to put them at the first place.